# How can Beautiful Soup loop through a list of URLs to scrape multiple text fields

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to loop through a stored list of URLs to scrape stats about footballers (age, name, club etc).

My list of URLs is stored as *playerLinks*

```
playerLinks[:5]
['https://footystats.org/players/england/martyn-waghorn',
 'https://footystats.org/players/norway/stefan-marius-johansen',
 'https://footystats.org/players/england/grady-diangana',
 'https://footystats.org/players/england/jacob-brown',
 'https://footystats.org/players/england/josh-onomah']
```

If i attempt to scrape an individual link with the following code I am able to retrieve a result.

```
testreq = Request('https://footystats.org/players/england/dominic-solanke', headers=headers)
html_test = urlopen(testreq)
testsoup = BeautifulSoup(html_test, "html.parser")
testname = testsoup.find('p','col-lg-7 lh14e').text
print(testname)
#Dominic Solanke
```

However, when I loop through my list of URLs I receive errors. Below is the code I am using, but to no avail.

```
names = []
#For each player page...
for i in range(len(playerLinks)):

    reqs2 = Request(playerLinks[i], headers=headers)
    html_page = urlopen(reqs2)
    
    psoup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
    
    for x in psoup2.find('p','col-lg-7 lh14e').text
        names.append(x.get('text'))
```

Once I fix the name scrape I will need to repeat the process for other stats. I have pasted the html of the page below. Do I need to nest another loop within? At the moment i receive either 'invalid syntax' errors or 'no text object' errors.

```
"<div class="row cf lightGrayBorderBottom "> <p class="col-lg-5 semi-bold lh14e bbox mild-small">Full Name</p> <p class="col-lg-7 lh14e">Dominic Solanke</p></div>"
```

Comment: You're missing the `:` at the end of the `for x` line.

Comment: You shouldn't have `.text` on the `for` line.

Comment: where should the .text go?
With the ':' added to the 'for x' line i receive this error:


     10     for x in psoup2.find('p','col-lg-7 lh14e').text:
---> 11         names.append(x.get('text'))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: It goes in `x.get('text')` on the next line, where you already have it.

Comment: `for x in psoup2.find('p','col-lg-7 lh14e'): names.append(x.get('text'))`

Comment: AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get'


Error coming from the names.append(x.get('text'))

Comment: `.text` is not bs4. use `.string`

Comment: It seems like you need to learn the basic use of bs4, before you worry about this more advanced question.

Comment: @cards that was where i started, although it gives the same result. Assuming you mean  
`for x in psoup2.find('p','col-lg-7 lh14e').string:`  

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: some of these links dont have content.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the following output:

Code:

```
import bs4, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


playerLinks=['https://footystats.org/players/england/martyn-waghorn',
 'https://footystats.org/players/norway/stefan-marius-johansen',
 'https://footystats.org/players/england/grady-diangana',
 'https://footystats.org/players/england/jacob-brown',
 'https://footystats.org/players/england/josh-onomah']

names = []
#For each player page...
for i in range(len(playerLinks)):

    reqs2 = requests.get(playerLinks[i])
    
    
    psoup2 = BeautifulSoup(reqs2.content, "html.parser")
    
    for x in psoup2.find_all('p','col-lg-7 lh14e'):
        names.append(x.text)
        print(names)
#print(names)
```

Output:

```
['Martyn Waghorn']
['Martyn Waghorn', 'England']
['Martyn Waghorn', 'England', 'Forward']
['Martyn Waghorn', 'England', 'Forward', '31 (23 January 1990)']
['Martyn Waghorn', 'England', 'Forward', '31 (23 January 1990)', '71st / 300 players']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 
That is partially working, however it is only returning the results for the first link from the playerLinks list (highlighting another issue with my code!)

Answer (score 0):

Some of these links are blank content. I suspect you need to either be logged in and/or be paying for a subscription (as the do offer an api...but the free one only allows for 1 league)

But to correct that output, move your print statement until the end as opposed to printing after every time you append to the list:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


playerLinks=['https://footystats.org/players/england/martyn-waghorn',
 'https://footystats.org/players/norway/stefan-marius-johansen',
 'https://footystats.org/players/england/grady-diangana',
 'https://footystats.org/players/england/jacob-brown',
 'https://footystats.org/players/england/josh-onomah']

names = []
#For each player page...
for link in playerLinks:
    w=1
    reqs2 = requests.get(link)
    
    
    psoup2 = BeautifulSoup(reqs2.content, "html.parser")
    
    for x in psoup2.find_all('p','col-lg-7 lh14e'):
        names.append(x.text)
print(names)
```